# Stored procedure call is very slow from Entity Framework 4 due to inexplicable reason

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Stored procedure (query ) when run in Management Studio takes 4-8 seconds. However, when launched inside WCF service via Entity Framework it may take more than minute. WCF runs in VS 2010 in debugging mode with ASP.Net Development Web Server.

The actual call

```
requests = transactionEntities.spRequestsForRescreening(cutoffDate).ToArray();
```

Since all SQL code encapsulated in a stored procedure don't know what I could look at to understand the reason causing this slowness.

Comment: Have you run a profiler against it to see where the wheel are spinning?

Also, try it without the ToArray, my experience has been that some of the conversions can be the issue, not the actual query.

Comment: @Benjamin
Profiler just shows stored procedure call. You comment implies that I can see more ?

Comment: You would, if it were getting past that point.

Answer (score 1):

While the call is running from the WCF call, you have a full minute to investigate what's going on. Check [`sys.dm_exec_requests`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) and inspect the WCF request. The relevant columns are:

- `wait_time`, `wait_type` and `wait_resource` to see what is blocking the execution (IO, locking, resource contention, slow client etc)
- `blocking_session_id` to see what other session is blocking execution
- `sql_handle`, `statement_start_offset` and `statement_end_offset` to understand which statement inside the SP is slow (cross apply [`sys.dm_exec_sql_text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929.aspx))
- `plan_handle` to inspect the execution plan (cross apply [`sys.dm_exec_query_plan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189747.aspx))

Inspect these values several times during execution, from an SSMS query window, to get a grasp of what is the call issues from WCF doing and why it takes so long.